# How can I control a specific door/s and lock/unlock the door/s instead a global one script for all doors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to a empty gameobject and control all the doors in the scene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool locked;
    public bool lockStateRealTime = false;
    public Renderer rend;
    public HoriDoorManager doorManager;


    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private GameObject[] doorPlanes;

    private void Start()
    {
        doorPlanes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorPlane");
        ChangeColors(new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255));
    }

    private void ChangeMaterialSettings()
    {
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/Color");
        rend.material.shader = unlitcolor;
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 1);
    }

    private void ChangeColors(Color32 lockedColor, Color32 unlockedColor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < doorPlanes.Length; i++)
        {
            rend = doorPlanes[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            ChangeMaterialSettings();
            if (locked)
            {
                doorManager.doorLockState = true;
                rend.material.color = lockedColor;
            }
            else
            {
                doorManager.doorLockState = false;
                rend.material.color = unlockedColor;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (lockStateRealTime)
        {
            ChangeColors(new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255));
            lockStateRealTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the HoriDoorManager script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DoorHori door1;
    public DoorHori door2;
    public bool doorLockState;

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {

        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (door1 != null)
            {
                door1.OpenDoor();
            }

            if (door2 != null)
            {
                door2.OpenDoor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now in my game I need to lock and unclock only specific doors. For example if I have 20 doors I need to have 3 of them unlocked when running the game.

What is the best way to control specific door/s before running the game ?

The main goal later is to make somehow a visual map of the doors or even of all my space station in the game and to be able to control objects through the map.

A dynamic map.

Comment: Is this different than making a door prefab with a script that handles collision?

Comment: `What is the best way to control specific door/s before running the game ?

Maybe there is a way to make a editor script or maybe editorwindow script with a visual map of all the doors and how they are connected by drawing lines and by clicking on a door in the map it will lock/unlock the door when running the game ? Also will lock/unlock in the editowindow visually somehow ? But now I think how I can control the doors before running the game ?` ... please limit it to one specific question ..

Comment: @derHugo you right, The main question is What is the best way to control specific door/s before running the game ?

Comment: and what id `HoriDoor`?

Comment: I don't see where this is going in the end but what about having a `Door : MonoBehaviour` on each door with a `public bool` locked?

Comment: @derHugo I added that script the HoriDoorManager script is attached to each door. But when doorLockState is true if I set it to true the door is locked but then the npc walk through the next door another door and then doorLockState is false since I set it to true only on one door. Then in the other script DoorsLockManager doorLockState is false and it's not changing the colors. The problem is that the npc is walking through more then one door so the state of the flag doorLockState change all the time.

Comment: Is `HoriDoorManager` intended to be able to manage the state of all the doors? My understanding of your question is that you would like to have a central place where you can track and control all the doors in your scene? Is that correct?

Comment: @ColinYoung The main idea is to be able to lock/unlock the doors before running the game and while the game is running. HoriDoorManager is attached to each door so in my logic HoriDoorManager should handle and control each individual door and my other script DoorsLockManager should handle and control all the doors at once either before running the game or while the game is running.

Comment: @ColinYoung In this link is a question I did a bit older with two screenshots explain about the doors much more: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1604113/how-can-i-control-each-door-lock-state-lockunlock.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to create a manager class that caches a reference to all the doors and then exposes lock and unlock methods and handles calling the underlying door objects. `DoorLocksManagers` should be renamed to `DoorLockManager` since it only handles a single door (although I'd probably merge it into the `HoriDoorManager`). Something like this:

```
class DoorsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<HoriDoorManager> _doors;

    private void Start()
    {
        // find all your doors and add them to the _doors collection
        // alternatively expose the collection to the UI and build it there
    }

    public void LockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(true);
    }
    public void UnlockDoor(int doorIndex)
    {
        _doors[doorIndex].ChangeLockState(false);
    }
}
```

Then before you start the game, just call LockDoor/UnlockDoor as appropriate with the index for each of the doors you want to affect. You might consider defining them as `LockDoor(params int[] indexes)` and then you could pass multiple indices at once. The same would be true during game play. You'd probably also expose methods to iterate through the cached doors and get their status, etc.

I'd also pull `unlitcolor` up to the manager class to avoid looking it up every single time.

Comment: What is Door in the List ? To find the doors I created a new Tag name Door and added the tag to all the doors and then did: _doors.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Door")); and the List is type GameObject not Door. Maybe you can show me the full code how it should look like ?

Comment: My apology. It it a collection of `HoriDoorManager` objects, after you've merged the lock manager class into it. I've updated the answer. Unless you are planning on unlocking things other than doors, I wouldn't create a separate class for just that, but, even if you are, I'd go with an interface and implement that in whichever classes needed unlocking.